# FindBugs and Nonnegative annotation (jsr 305)

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs, jsr305

Has anyone got `@Nonnegative` to work with FindBugs, maybe FindBugs contrib ?
Which package do you use, javax.annotation ?

Any other tool to check it (apart of IntelliJ) ?

Comment: I don't think FindBugs knows `@Nonnegative`, because it is not mentioned among the [FindBugs annotations](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html). Then again, there is [this unresolved bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/719/) ...